# I need help for my navbar with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm doing a project with vueJS with a login page. The probleme is that i don't know if it's possible to show the navbar on all my pages except my login page (www.mysite.com/) ?
Thank you and have a nice day,
Alec.

Comment: Please show some code.  Please provide details about your project, what you have tried, how your navbar works, and why you think you can/can't display your navbar conditionally.  Your question is too broad is it stands right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use $route.name :

```
<nav v-if="$route.name != 'login'"> </nav>
```

'login' : change it with the name of your login page.

here an example : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/254